# Advice for new comers into the .NET world for web developers

Tags: .net

I am wondering what would be a good ramp up plan that you can recommend a typical ASP.NET web developer who is a totally new to .NET world. There are way too many things to learn, and too little time to train.

C#

ASP.NET

ASP.NET MVC

JQuery

AJAX

Silverlight

RIA

WCF

... list goes on ...

Comment: What is your background? If you come from a Java background the answer is very different to coming from a perl background.

Comment: I think it also depends on the type of sites you wish to build.

Comment: The guys are fresh graduates who are hired straight from colleges. The course curriculum teaches C, C++, Java but that's only from project perspective. Finding it pretty difficult to formulate a good ramp up plan for the new joinees.

Comment: then the best place to start is at the beginning... walk through the .NET framework, then introduce C# (Which should be childs play) then the specific C# .NET bits (generics, delegates etc), and then onwards and upwards to ASP.NET from there.

Comment: For a fresh graduate, provide him/her with a basic application (which has already some functionality), so that they can learn quickly by looking at the code and then ask them to add more and more functionality to that application. Reading a good book is very important. Have an hour of daily session with them, where they can ask queries and someone can answer them. Some of them catch things up quickly and some will take time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order of first to last:

1. C# (and the .NET framework)
2. ASP.NET
3. ASP.NET Web Services
4. JQuery
5. AJAX
6. ASP.NET MVC

Reasons: Well you need to know C# or VB.NET to start using ASP.NET. Then to develop web apps in .NET you need ASP.NET, and most enterprise applications use WebServices to enforce layered application design patterns. After that jQuery is useful, and then when you know jQuery you can choose between jQuery to AJAXify your pages, or ASP.NET AJAX. Up to you... After that I would look at ASP.NET MVC to pull things together (And rewrite your original project ;-)).

I have left off Silverlight, RIA and WCF because they are not 'essential' in my opinion for entry level leaning, unless you specifically need them. Web Services are more than sufficient for most applications where WCF could be used. RIA's are nice, but they 'come along' with your knowledge of AJAX and ASP.NET. Silverlight is very nice... But again IMO not essential learning for a beginner.

This would be where I started... http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-C-2005-with-NET-3-0.productCd-0470124725.html Though there is a newer one now. It walks you though the CLR, then the C# language, and then you can choose to read the WinForms, WPF, or ASP.NET chapters followed by WCF/WebServices etc...

Answer (score 1):

The first piece of advice I would give you would be to understand how the technologies you listed can, but certainly don't have to, relate.  You are talking about server-side, client-side, browser plugins, etc.

What you need is a project.  Don't feel you have to throw the kitchen sick at a problem just because you can.  Get yourself a project and learn as you go.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend looking at the certification exams and, if not actually doing the exams, then reading the Microsoft Press Self-Paced Training Kit.

Here is the WCF book (Exam 70-503):
http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Book.aspx?ID=12486&locale=en-us

If you are really committed, have a go at getting the [MCPD Enterprise Application Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/mcpd.aspx#tab2) certification, although it might take a few months of part time effort.

Comment: Good idea to recommend the books, but... 'A few months'?!!? - Microsoft recommend 2 years before sitting ANY of their MCTS exams (Of which you will need to pass 2 to get MCTS). I don't think that a 'few months' would cut the mustard for MCPD...

Comment: I had a look at @Rahuls SO profile and saw that he already has a fair bit of c#/web development experience - I see now he has commented that it is not for him :)

Comment: I think there would be something very wrong if 2 months from beginner could create a MCPD... lol

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this...

1. C#
2. Entity Framework (or NHibernate, depending on taste)
3. ASP.Net MVC
4. HTML
5. Javascript/Jquery

This is all you need to build a small to medium size web application. Don't worry about web services, RIA, Silverlight, WCF, etc. until you are comfortable with the basics.

Comment: Whilst it is more than possible to create a web app with these technologies, I don't agree with leaving out Web Services. The OP is training new graduates. Surely they should be taught current best practise, not just thrown the monkey and told to make it dance.